# Where does gitosis store the working copies?

Tags: git, gitosis, working-copy

i wonder where gitosis stores the working copies of my repositories. I can see the filetree with the gitweb interface but cant find any working copy in /srv/gitosis/repositories/testrepo. Iam also able to push and clone to the repo.

But how can i manage to write my deploy-script without knowing the path of the working copy?

Answer (score 4):

gitosis stores repositories bare, that is, without a working directory at all.  You will have to clone `/srv/gitosis/repositories/testrepo` somewhere else for deployment.

Comment: so when i edit a file and push it... i have to add the fetch-command for my cloned repo, to the deploy-script. Thnk u =)