# Where does Gitosis store its files?

Tags: git, gitosis

Firstly, I know about this post: [Where does gitosis store the working copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308128/where-does-gitosis-store-the-working-copies). But I'm consider to create this message to concrete the answer of that.

[Where does gitosis store the working copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308128/where-does-gitosis-store-the-working-copies#comment4677945_4308150)

Can anybody, please, make some concrete?

Can I do this trick via post hooks? I have exactly same problem, and think about how to make newly pushed files accessible for a web server virtualhost, where's application is store.

Are there any examples maybe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4308128/6309) was:

> how can I manage to write my deploy-script without knowing the path of the working copy?

The answer is: you alone can determine that path, because gitosis like gitolite only manage bare repos, which, as their name suggests (bare) are *without* working tree.

I would suggest to:

- use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) instead of gitosis (obsolete and no longer maintained)
- [use a VREF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888300/gitosis-vs-gitolite/10888358#10888358) (an update hook) which can deploy the repo in any working tree of your choice, with a hook content [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892791/6309).

Comment: As I understand - the destination directory, where checkout will be do, must be initialized as a non-bare repository, right?

Comment: @Evgeniy yes, it can be as simple as cloning the bare repo in the destination directory. That clone will be by default a non-bare one.

Comment: I have to come back to this йгуыешщт in order to clarify one thing. Which method could be fine to correct the permissions when using this hook? I mean we have a user for git, and we have an apache user. Hook works just fine, but the user is git:git, for example. What is the best practice to change it for an apache, so there are right perms for the web server?

Comment: @Evgeniy For instance, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7545029/6309 with a sudo to execute as apache.